# Ground states of Chiral Boson Theory with tunneling

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order, bosons, chirality

I am reading [this paper](http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/pub/cll.pdf)(pdf) and on page 11, the chiral boson theory on a cylinder is studied when both edges of the cylinder are brought in close proximity so that electron is allowed.

Why is it that for large tunneling amplitudes, $g$, the field $\phi$ can be
treated 'classically' in the sense that it gets pinned to the classical 
minima of the cosine to obtain the ground state energy?

Could someone give a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 2):

It is simply the fact that if the $g$ is large,
$$
g \cos(\hat{\phi}) \to g(1- \frac{1}{2}\hat{\phi}^2 +\dots)
$$
the ground state will be trapped in one of the vacuum sectors, at the minimum of the potential energy. (Please check S Coleman's book $\it{Aspects\; of\; symmetry}$ or his Phys Rev D paper on quantum sine-Gordon eq. It may offer differ views than what I said. If so, please report to me. :-))

It is **NOT** the only way to treat in the $\phi$ space and counting the minimum vacuum energy, and further count (topological) ground state degeneracy, and module out the equivalence classes. You can **also** treat in the **dual conjugate momentum** of the field $\phi$ variable. In a compact 1+1D boundary, the mode expansion of $\phi$ is

$$
\hat{\Phi}_I(x) ={\hat{\phi}_{0}}_{I}+K^{-1}_{IJ} \hat{P}_{\phi_J} \frac{2\pi}{L}x+i \sum_{n\neq 0} \frac{1}{n} \hat{\alpha}_{I,n} e^{-in x \frac{2\pi}{L}} 
$$

In the sense of large coupling limit, from the view points of the mode expansion of $\phi$, the topological features is controlled by the nontrivial [zero modes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74081/zero-modes-zero-eigenvalue-modes-zero-energy-modes): $\phi_0$. The dual conjugate variable of $\phi_0$ variable is the nontrivial [winding mode](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74081/zero-modes-zero-eigenvalue-modes-zero-energy-modes), $p_\phi$.

Please see [this paper arxiv-1212.4863](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4863). You can construct the Hilbert space of either zero modes $\phi_0$, or the Hilbert space of winding mode, $p_\phi$. Both approaches should give the same consistent result, though constructing the Hilbert space of winding modes $p_\phi$ has some better advantages than $\phi_0$ in the case of modding out equivalence classes. See Appendix B of [this paper arxiv-1212.4863](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4863) for some highly relevant discussions.

ps. everything listed above can be treated as operator levels, not just classical fields. i.e.
$\phi \to \hat{\phi}$

Comment: Thanks for the nice reply. I think the problem that I am/was having was that I did understand the intuitive picture (meaning that for large g the field is trapped in the minima of the cosine and cannot escape by any 'flunctuations'). The problem was rather on a formal level, in the sense that one is threating $\phi$ as if wasn't an operator but a normal complex function (i.e. a classical field). Maybe you can elaborate on this.

Comment: My response: every fields listed above can be treated as quantum operators, not just classical fields. i.e. $\phi \to \hat{\phi}$. e.g. construct a Hilbert space of $\hat{\phi}_0$ or $\hat{P}_\phi$ certainly means the Hilbert space acted by operators. But honestly, the first part, "how can I consider $\phi$ treated at the minimum at large $g$?" - this is simply based on my physics intuition. (Doing physics relies on some intuition/approximation?) I have no further proof for this. Perhaps let me know if Coleman or others offers some formal answer for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For formal proof, I suggest to compute the correlator $\langle \hat{\phi}(0) \hat{\phi}(x) \rangle$ where $0$ and $x$ are two different minimum (vacuum expectation values). I suppose this value has exponential decay $\exp[-g \cdot\; \text{const} \cdot \text{volume}]$(?), with an exponent of some factor proportional to the volume of the spacetime of fields. (yes?)

Comment: Did you set t=0 in your mode expansion above or does "x" correspond to some "lightcone-like" coordinate?

Comment: I set t=0. It just a matter of Schrodinger picture of Heisenberg picture. You can add $e^{iHt}$ and $e^{-iHt}$ on two sides of $\Phi$.